# React interface function throwing error when compiling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new to react and learning react on my own. I have the following error when I try to compile my project. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

```
interface ConfirmProps{
  title : string;
  content : string;
  cancelCaption? : string;
  okCaption? :string;
  onOkClick: () => void;
}


const Confirm = (props: ConfirmProps) => {
  const {title, content, cancelCaption, okCaption, onOkClick}= props;

  const handleOkClick = () => {
    onOkClick();
  };
```

error I am getting

```
Property 'onOkClick' is missing in type '{ title: string; content: string; cancelCaption: string; okCaption: string; }' but required in type 'ConfirmProps'.  TS2741
```

pic
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the properties onClick is a required prop.

To match that contract you can:

a) Make the prop optional. Notice the question mark `.?` and the `onOkClick && onOkClick();`:

```
interface ConfirmProps{
  title : string;
  content : string;
  cancelCaption? : string;
  okCaption? :string;
  onOkClick?: () => void;
}


const Confirm = (props: ConfirmProps) => {
  const {title, content, cancelCaption, okCaption, onOkClick}= props;

  const handleOkClick = () => {
    onOkClick && onOkClick();
  };
```

Or

b) You have to pass the a function when using Confirm in the parent Component

```
<Confirm
title= "title"
content= "content of confirm"
cancelCaption="No Way"
onClick={() => {/**Do something here**/}}
/>
```